# Can I create a DACPAC for installing DDL against a mySQL database

Tags: mysql, tfs, dacpac

Currently we are planning on releasing database changes using DACPAC's for SQL Server. We are planning on building applications for mySQL and we need a way to build releases for code that will get checked into TFS. Is it possible to create a DACPAC and run it against a mySQL database? If DACPAC's won't work, does anyone have a better suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Dacpac files are SQL Server specific and the tools do not support any other RDBMS.

Comment: I realize that it was written for SQL Server. But I saw another article suggesting that it could be done. Hence, I asked the question to see if anyone is doing this.